# How are separate responsibilities created in symfony?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, symfony

This question is a bit hard to explain, but I'll try my best.

Say, I am creating an job add aggregator site. For this, I have 10 job sites I will crawl through, parse the HTML 
and get all the juices.

Now, since each sites template, url and the amount of information they contain is unique, something tells me the crawling part
should be organized separately.

Normally, I could put it all together in

```
class CrawlerController extends Controller {

    public function fooDotComAction(){

    }

    public function barDotNetAction(){

    }
}
```

You can see the above is still better than dumping all my crawler logic inside the DefaultController, 
but even my example doesn't seem efficient, or modular.

It seems like a bad practice, I am wandering if there is some sort of feature in Symfony that 
provides an implementation or guide for such problems.

Comment: Doing the crawling in a controller seems like a bad start. You probably will want to create a service that does the crawling. A good idea might be to write one service/class per site to crawl, ideally implementing a common interface. To actually run these services would be better suited from the command line, so you might want to consider writing commands for that.

Comment: @Gerry Yeah, that sounds like what I was looking for. Now the problem is finding out what a service is, how to create is and integrate it in the app

Comment: A service basically is a plain PHP class, eg `FooDotComCrawler`. Once you have written it, you can register it in the DIC to use in your controllers and commands, see http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html

Comment: This is primarily opinion-based question, so not really a good fit for SO. But still, do not over-think it. Develop according to your present abilities, read on design patterns and SOLID principles, check out other implementations, and little by little patterns will emerge for you. But whatever design you end up choosing, no matter your level of experience, in some time will appear dated to your eyes. Is better to have something functional **now** than something **perfect** never.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad but you have find the design pattern who will fit your needs then implement it. You will need to create php class and to declare them as services.

Symfony promotes the ideas of service-oriented architecture and has powerful solution for separation of concerns: [The Dependency Injection Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html). In short, this component provides [implementation of the Service Container](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html): a tool for configuration, binding and creation of the separate service objects.

Your business code will be contain in domain services and your controller will just organize the input and output and call the domain services

Comment: But this answer is diverse as it is, do you have any technical solution? I will read the manual but an example helps a lot

Comment: @mvrht, you cant expect a very concrete answer on a very open-ended question.

Comment: @Gerry Yeah, I understand that is what's confusing the hell out of me

Comment: @mvrh No sorry, but you can maybe check some projects on github?

Answer (score 0):

check out https://codereviewvideos.com/blog/symfony-compiler-pass-tutorial/

and the 2 linked videos and explanations. ([1](https://codereviewvideos.com/course/symfony-compiler-pass-example/video/extract-extract-extract), [2](https://codereviewvideos.com/course/symfony-compiler-pass-example/video/extract-extract-extract))

it will show you how you can, in a clean way,   seperate each 'crawler', using tagged services and a compiler pass, which i *think* would be a clean way of doing this .

Comment: The videos no longer exist